# Web Application + Mobile Application Development - Suggestions

Tags: web-applications

I am in the very initial stages of developing a web application. the requirement is that the same application should also be developed as a native ios application for ipad later. I have chosen the following method. do let me know if there is going to be any problem if i take this approach.

1. Exposing the common functionality as a **RESTful webservice using Microsoft WCF**.
2. Developing an **asp.net MVC 3 web application**. it will consume the RESTful webservice for        required functionalities. - Phase I of the project
3. Developing the **ios application using objective C** for ipad. it will consume the RESTful webservice for required functionalities. - Phase II of the project

I never worked on anything other than Microsoft .net technologies for application development. For ios application development i will be getting 
enough time to learn and develop the application, but we have to deliver the first leg of the project(web application) as soon as possible and at the same time i would like to make sure that the web service we are developing now can be used later in the ios application development.

Let me know if there is any better way to do this. thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is a question to be posted on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), check out their [faq](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: You should be able to use web services from objective-c. But if you are a C# developer you might want to take a look at [mono touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoTouch#MonoTouch). You write your ios app in c# and it compiles to native ios. I have not used it, just a thought. Might make integration easier.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be having issues with [RESTful](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx) webservice usage on the IOS side. On the other hand, if your application has no mobile specific functionalities you could develop a common WEB UI for both side and call the mobile from IOS's web browser component. You might want to check [VisualJS.NET](http://visualjs.net) for this